# What do I need to do to port an admin application to frontend?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a simple admin database. I want to port it to search and results pages. How do I achieve this? Thanks

**EDIT re Jonathan Fingland's comment**

```
from django.db import models

class Lawyer(models.Model):
    firm_url = models.CharField('Bio', max_length=200)
    firm_name = models.CharField('Firm', max_length=100)
    first = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=50)
    last = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=50)
    year_graduated = models.IntegerField('Year graduated')
    school = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('last',)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first
```

Comment: This Question needs significant improvement before anyone can answer this. What's your rdbms? What's the schema look like?

Comment: What does this question even mean? Do you mean you have an admin-only Django application and you want to put non-admin views on it? If so, is there any reason why you can't read the documentation?

Comment: Yes, I have an admin-only application and I want to keep the same look and functionality. I would appreciate if you point me in the right place in the documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much experience do you have with Django? If you have an admin-only site, perhaps you've only ever really worked with the model layer of Django's model-view-template architecture. I think you can answer your own question by reading the documentation and tutorials more thoroughly (check out [djangobook.com](http://www.djangobook.com/)). However, as an example to get you started:

For a simple search page, you want to make a template that has a form in it. There will be a text box for the search query. The "submit" button would have some url as its target. That URL will correspond to a view function. And view function will take the text that the user typed in, perform a database query, and end up with a list of Lawyer objects.

As for the results: this same search view function will render a template. It will send it some data, which will include (possibly among other things), the list of lawyer objects. Then, in your result template, you simply loop through all of the lawyers in your list and display them all somehow in HTML. (eg: for each lawyer, `<li>Last name, first name: Firm</li>`).

I'm not giving you specific code, because there is a fair amount of it to write and it will depend on your implementation. This should give you an idea of how to get started... now go read some documentation and examples! I'm sure you can google "django search form" and find a good example.

**Edit**: [Here's an actual example in the Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter07/) that walks you through making a search page.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you, this is what I needed. Yes, I only worked with admin so far and I want to expand my knowledge.

Comment: Good! I'm glad that helps. Have fun--you're about to be able to do the cool stuff with your Django app.