# How to refine an initial query in Django?

Tags: python, django

Following the reply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030757/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-port-an-admin-application-to-frontend) (Thanks again Ellie P!) I created a search page and a results page.

For instance if you [search](http://swimswith.com/search-form/) for the lawyer "delelle" the result page shows her firm, school and year graduated. But instead of displaying her info, I want to display other lawyers who graduated from the same school the same year.

This is the view:

```
def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
        lawyers = Lawyer.objects.filter(last__icontains=q)
        return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'lawyers': lawyers, 'query': q})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

Can anyone help me understand how I can save the `school` and `year_graduated` from the initial query and do a `school` and `year_graduated` search and display that result?

Thank you!

**Edit**

Model is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030757/what-do-i-need-to-do-to-port-an-admin-application-to-frontend)

**Edit2**

I tried a few things from the [QuerySet API](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api)

Given the search query is "akira":

```
>>> akira_year = Lawyer.objects.filter(first__icontains="Akira").values_list('year_graduated').order_by('year_graduated')

>>> print akira_year
[(u'2000',)]
```

But

```
>>> Lawyer.objects.filter(year_graduated__icontains=akira_year[0])
[]
```

doesn't work.

Can anyone help with the correct syntax to use in this case?

Thanks

Comment: You must explain a little more, what you are trying to achieve, because right now it's hard to understand.

Comment: First don't pass the search to the model directly use something like django-sphinx, You have to post your model for other to answer your question.

Comment: I added the link to the model.

Comment: gruszczy: When the user searches for last name the result page will return the names of all lawyers who graduated from same school the same year. At this point the search returns the info for the last name searched. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This view function answers the question:

```
def search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET and request.GET['q']:
        q = request.GET['q']
        q_school = Lawyer.objects.filter(last__icontains=q).values_list('school', flat=True)
        q_year = Lawyer.objects.filter(last__icontains=q).values_list('year_graduated', flat=True)
        lawyers = Lawyer.objects.filter(school__icontains=q_school[0]).filter(year_graduated__icontains=q_year[0])        
        return render_to_response('search_results.html', {'lawyers': lawyers, 'query': q})
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```